# SQL Conditional SELECT from CSV

Tags: c#, sql, csv

I'm trying to load data from a CSV file using an SQL query `SELECT * FROM ["+fileName+"];`. It works as expected when I select all data with no condition, however, I would like to omit any records containing the string ".BAK" in the first column. Does anyone have any insight into how I could achieve this?

I've attempted variations of the `WHERE NOT LIKE '%.BAK%'` condition, but I can't get them to work as expected.

Thanks

Comment: have you entered the correct column 'WHERE col1 NOT LIKE '%.BAK%'? can you post the full query?

Comment: How do you connect to your Text file? Do you have HDR=YES or you don't have any name for your columns?

Comment: SELECT * FROM ["+fileName+"]; is the full working query. Then i tried to tack on 
WHERE column(1) NOT LIKE '%.BAK%' 
WHERE (1) NOT LIKE '%.BAK%'
WHERE [1] NOT LIKE '%.BAK%'
and substituted 0 in place of 1 as well.
I don't have a column name in the CSV so my reference to the first column by number may be the issue.

Comment: @Steve I connect to the CSV file via OleDb objects- using the sql query I fill an adapter
I don't have column names and the first row is not the header so i have HDR=NO in the connection string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your CSV file contains, in the first line, the column headers (for example)

```
firstHeaderName,secondHeaderName,thirdHeaderName, ......
```

then the query to execute is simply

```
string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM [" + filename + "] WHERE firstHeaderName NOT LIKE '%.bak%'";
```

Things are similar if you don't have a line with the column headers in the first line of your CSV.
In this case the connectionstring is something like this

```
string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
                  Data Source=d:\temp\;
                  Extended Properties='text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited'";
```

and your command text should refer to the first column using the conventional name **F1**

```
string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM [" + filename + "] WHERE F1 NOT LIKE '%.bak%'";
```

The convention is to name the columns with **F1** (the first column), **F2** (the second column) and so on.

Comment: That was it man! "F1" was the column name I needed to reference.
Thank you so much!!